# The simplest workspace switcher?

Tags: workspaces, dock, workspace-switcher

I don't need any workspace previews or big workspace switcher widgets. I just want simple workspace switcher like on [iOS springboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpringBoard). Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a question: how do you (in particular) use workspaces? I'm new to Linux and can't quite get my head around the idea of separate workspaces.

Comment: I use workspaces to separate tasks, such as coding, drawing and web browsing. Workspaces can be switched in Gnome panel (Gnome session) or by other commands configured for example in CompizConfig Settings Manager

Comment: @EmmyS , Its better opening a New Question for that... It is in the top right of your screen.

Comment: @michealH - I know how to ask a new question. But usually, questions like, "how do you personally use a feature" get closed because it's too vague, or subjective.

Comment: @Anergy - thanks. I do know *how* to switch workspaces; I'm just a little fuzzy on *why*, so I've been asking everyone I can find who uses them for examples of how they use them.

Comment: @EmmyS I think "What tips do you have for using workspaces?" would be a great CW question!

Comment: @Jorge - OK, what's CW?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I've added Super+Left and Super+Right shortcuts. And since I've created simple workspace switcher applet, the question is closed.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest Docky , which is a free application that I use alot! Just run `sudo apt-get install docky`. For the icons you can just look around, With docky you may also have multiple dock :)

Comment: thank you for suggestion. I tried docky, but as far as I know it doesn't have workspace switcher. I found gpager, it's even resizable, but it displays annoying previews! [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/ylaCW.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the gnome applet, right click> add to panel> find workspace swicher.

Or you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> keys for changing the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

As Jorge Castro says, there are some desktop shortcuts.

And why not go one step further and make <kbd>Windows</kbd>+number switch to that workspace?

- Go to System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts
- Scroll down until you see `Switch to workspace 1`
- Click on the `Disabled` field to the right
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- Repeat for workspaces 2, 3, and 4.

When you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, etc. it will appear as `Mod4+1`.  That is normal.

Answer (score 1):

[Cairo Dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/) can be configured to look very similar to springboard and also provides a workspace switcher:

[image]

For fast switching when your mouse is at your screen edge you can also give [Brightside](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/brightside) a try.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I'm fully satisfied with awn and gnome-panel. I created gnome-panel applet using libwnck today, but I have no experience in making packages for ubuntu, so someone may feel free to use source http://snipt.org/wlggk